# Parallele HTTP API call in spark

Tags: python, scala, http, apache-spark

I am trying to achieve following two objectives.

a. Calling multiple HTTP apis in  form of one API per partition

b. Coalesce the result of all partition in one dataframe with sequence preserved.

As per my research,I can do following steps :

1. Creating sequence of HTTP API url strings and then parallelise them in one dataframe.
2. using `mapPartitions` to call method doing api call which as per my understanding will call api in each partition.

Is this the correct approach and also how do i make sure that data is arrived 
in each partition before coalescing.

Comment: 1 sounds right, but I think you can use `dataset.map` instead of `dataset.mapPartition`. Spark takes care of the parallelizing the work and ensuring it's spread out over the works then returns a dataset with results.

Comment: @BiRico my goal is to execute HTTP APIs in parallel manner so to improve time instead of doing it in loop manner.So asking for best possible options

Comment: Spark dataframes are parallel and distributed by design. Your plan will be executed by all available slots, you don't need to add another layer of parallelism. What have you tried, how is it different than your goal?